# storing output of a command that fails to execute

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying store the output of command to a variable in a script and print the result depending on output stored in variable..

For example, in this script, I am trying print the status of an agent installed on few systems read from lab.txt file. If the status matches with "isrunning", it prints that "agent is installed".

```
~]#  cat lab.txt
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
```

Here is the script -

```
#!/bin/bash
while read host; do
status=$(ssh -n root@$host /opt/agent/bin/agent.sh status | awk 'NR==1{print $3 $4}')

if [ $status != isrunning ]
then
echo "agent is not installed"
else
echo "agent is installed"
fi
done < lab.txt
```

The issue here is, if the command returns an error as becuase the /opt/agent directory was not present on system 192.168.1.2, the "agent is not installed" message is not printed. What could be wrong here?

```
~]# ./script.sh

   root@192.168.1.1:

   agent is installed

   root@192.168.1.2:

   bash: /opt/agent/bin/agent.sh: No such file or directory
   ./script.sh: line 5: [: !=: unary operator expected
   agent is installed
```

Answer (score 1):

`$status` is not initialized, so the condition `[  status != isrunning ]` is not satisfied. Something like:

```
if [ "$status" != isrunning ]
```

should solve this and get rid of your error of `unary operator expected` too.